# Why the first if statement is failing?

Tags: java, if-statement

Edit: Apologize for confusing some of you, here is little more details.

I am very new to the stackoverflow. So I apologize in advance for a stupid questions.

I came across the below exercise in Udemy and my code is failing. Please help me understand why it is failing?

Description of the exercise:

> Write a method shouldWakeUp that has 2 parameters.
>
> 1st parameter should of type boolean and be named barking it represents if our dog is currently barking
>
> 2nd parameter represents the hour of day and is of the type int with the name hourOfDay and has a valid range of 0-23
>
> we have to wake up if the dog is barking before 8 or after 22 hours so that in that case return true, in all other case return false.
>
> if the hourOfDay parameter is less than 0 or greater 23 return false

```java
    public class BarkingDog {

        public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {

            if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22) {
                return true;
            } else if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is failing? This code will do what you said. It returns `true` for numbers like `5` or `23` and `false` for numbers from `8` to `22`, like `13`. Note that you could rewrite this method to just `return hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22;`, this is equivalent to what you have right now.

Comment: For what purpose do you provide boolean parameter to this method? You can also remove else-if block, since it is redunant

Comment: Downvoted because unclear. The question does exactly what you described. Please provide more detail why you think it is failing and how you measured this.

Comment: @Zabuza receiving the following error when running the code "method call shouldWakeUp(false, -5) returned a value of "true" but "false" was expected "

Comment: You're not checking the `barking` flag: "we have to wake up **if the dog is barking** before [...]"

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement fails because you are not checking if it’s barking and conditions for less than 0 or greater than 23.

You need to do the following

```
public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
if (barking) {
    if ((hourOfDay > 0 && hourOfDay < 8) || (hoursOfDay > 22 && hoursOfDay <23)) {
    return true;
  }
}
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment:

> "method call shouldWakeUp(false, -5) returned a value of "true" but "false" was expected

Its not very weird:

```
 if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22) {
        return true;
    }
```

If hourOfDay = -5, it is

```
hourOfDay < 8
```

So it will return True. Since your 2nd if statement checks if it is smaller than 0, this might seems weird. But your 2nd if statement is never reached.

If a number is smaller than 0, it is also smaller then 5.

In order to fix this you can do the following:

```
 public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
    if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Now we check if the value is less than 0 (so -1,-2,-3,etc) or larger than 23 (so 24,25,26,etc) then we return false. In all other cases we return true (this means between 0 and 23)

Edit: ofc you should use the boolean (barking) you provide in the function to check the time and return accordingly as the assignment describes, but I left that out and think you can fix that yourself.

Comment: thank you for solid explanation, what you have said totally make sense,but when running your code it is failing it is saying : "method call shouldWakeUp (false, 6) returned the value of true, was expected false;"

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit, you have to include the barking. If barking is false you can return false.  If barking is true, you have to check the times to see if you return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description provided, your method should return `false` if the time is in invalid range i.e `< 0 or > 23`. 
In your code, when you give invalid time range say -5, it checks against the first condition and the condition is satisfied because, -5 is lesser than 8. So it returns `true`.  Generally what you should do is always put your guard conditions(which returns `false`) at first.

So, your code should become as this,
**[Edited]**

```
public class BarkingDog {
    public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
        if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
            return false;
        } else if (hourOfDay >= 8 && hourOfDay <= 22) {
            return false;
        }
        return barking;
    }
}
```

**Things to consider while writing these kinds of conditions**

1. As said before, try to put all guard conditions at first. Hence it is called as `guard`. Think it of as a security dog infront of a building. It guards the method by checking all of the invalid checks at first returns the control immediately if it doesn’t satisfy.
2. Ordering of numerical check should be in ascending order. In your case the values(`8`) you checked against in your first condition is greater than the values(`0`). So you have to move this condition up a step. Actually this may confuse you in the beginning when you are using conditions with `&&` or `||` Boolean operators.

These are some of the tips you can have.

Comment: thanks for great explanation, but when trying the above code it is still failing..

Comment: @Sino In the above code I have not considered `barking` argument.  I left it out to you.

Comment: @Sino now I have included `barking` argument also.